# GMSMutablePath remove/replace coordinate issue, polyline

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm building an app that uses the Google Maps Directions API to give me a route polyline so I can display on my mapView to the users. Kind of like the Google Maps turn-by-turn service, but inside my app.

The markers on this map are the coordinates of the polyline that Google Directions gave

[image]

All the above coordinates (the markers) are stored in variable "path", which is a GMSMutablePath. Whenever the user's location is near a coordinate on the path (traveling in order so coordinate 0 first, then 1..) I remove that coordinate from the path via removeCoordinateAtIndex(), so that the polyline disappears (for ex: from marker 0 to marker 1) from my map. The purpose is that I want the polyline to always start displaying from the user's location, and not the origin of my route.

**Issue:**
However, I'm not sure why but the if statement that leads to removeCoordinateAtIndex() seems to only delete when I am on the index 0.. 2.. 4 (even) on path (my GMSMutablePath), so skipping one in between.

Here is my locationManager function

```
pathIndex = 0

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]

    /*
        For each GPS update, check location of user against next waypoint 
    on route. If distance is within 6 meters (18 feet), increment pathIndex 
    and now draw polyline from current location to NEXT waypoint (if there  
    is one), and then compare user location to NEXT waypoint again, etc.
    */

    //Replace polyline to start display from where you are
    path.replaceCoordinateAtIndex(UInt(0), withCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude))
    polyline.path = path

    //Get distance from current to next waypoint in path
    let waypoint = CLLocation(latitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(pathIndex)).latitude, longitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(pathIndex)).longitude) //Coordinate of next waypoint
    let locToWaypoint = location.distanceFromLocation(waypoint) //Returns distance in meters
    print("dist: ", locToWaypoint, ", index: ", pathIndex)

    //If closer than 6 meters, remove polyline of that segment from map
    if (locToWaypoint < 6) {
        //If not on last step
        if (pathIndex < Int(path.count()) - 1) {
            pathIndex++
            //Remove last path
            print("Removing: ", path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(0)))
            path.removeCoordinateAtIndex(UInt(0))

        }
    }
}
```

I have the feeling it is skipping deleting because of the 0s in

```
path.removeCoordinateAtIndex(Uint(0))
path.replaceCoordinateAtIndex(UInt(0), withCoordinate: ...)
```

But after changing it around, I'm still getting the same issue, so I think it might be another thing.

This is the **debug log**. Notice that only the first and third call removes the coordinate, the second call down. This changes to second and fourth call when I initiate pathIndex to 1 instead (always skipping one in between):

```
dist: 0.0 , index:  0       
Removing:  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.131648, longitude: -80.275542)  //First time, so is removed. This is the origin.
dist: 40.3950268964149 , index:  1     //Now showing dist to next waypoint

dist: 14.8659227375514 , index:  1  //Second time; NOT removed. Somehow it just skips the coordinate at the index and goes on to calculate the distance to the NEXT waypoint (thus 14.86)

dist: 1.34445248711346 , index:  1  
Removing:  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.131931, longitude: -80.2758)   //Third time, IS removed.
dist: 45.4634994640154 , index:  2     //Now showing dist to next waypoint
```

What is it doing that is making it skip the second waypoint/coordinate?

**PS:** When I call removeCoordinateAtIndex(0), does everything slide back down one spot? For example, if the path before remove is: [0, 1, 2, 3], will the path after remove be: [1, 2, 3] (so resized), or actually [ , 1, 2, 3] with a blank at index 0?

Comment: what is pathIndex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the problem!**

The line

```
let waypoint = CLLocation(latitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(pathIndex)).latitude, longitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(pathIndex)).longitude)
```

Should be reading:

```
let waypoint = CLLocation(latitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(1)).latitude, longitude: path.coordinateAtIndex(UInt(1)).longitude)
```

Instead. Notice the change from pathIndex -> 1, so now distanceFromLocation will always be comparing just to the next coordinate in path.